# Is the set of interval of the form $[a,b)$ in the set of real numbers a basis for some topology?

Tags: general-topology

> Prove that each of following are bases for topologies on the prescribed sets:
>
> the set of interval of the form $[a,b)$ in the set of real numbers.

I think it is because Let $X=[a,b)$. This is a real line, every open set in $X$ can be represent as union of member of $B=\{x∈X|x∈(a,b)\}$, so this is a basis.But I'm not sure I know how to prove this formally.

Comment: Yes, it's a basis. But not of the usual topology on $\Bbb R$. It generates the so-called [*Sorgenfrey Line*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology).

Comment: Are you asking if the collection of half-open intervals of the form $[a,b)$ forms a basis of the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, or just if it forms a basis for *some* topology on $\mathbb{R}$? Or is your whole space such an interval instead of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I fixed the question , now it's exactly the same to what written in the book. I'm not sure I understand what are they asking either.

Comment: Note, paraphrased, it says a basis for *a topology*. It does not say "a basis for the usual topology". So you need only verify that the collection satisfies the axioms that  a basis must satisfy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is basically is there some topology for which your family of sets forms a base. As you probably know, there are $2$ things a family $\cal A$ of sets must fulfill in order to be a base:

- It must cover the whole space, so in your case, the following must hold:
  $$\bigcup_{a,b\in\mathbb R}[a,b)=\mathbb R.$$
- Any intersection of two base sets must be a union of base sets, in other words, for $[a_1,b_1)$ and $[a_2,b_2)$, you must prove that:
  $$\forall x \in [a_1,b_1)\cap [a_2,b_2) \exists a<b\in \mathbb R: x\in[a,b)\wedge [a,b)\subseteq  [a_1,b_1)\cap [a_2,b_2)$$

With very little work, you should be able to prove both statements in minutes.

Comment: it can be an open set, since I can fit a ball inside it, am I correct?

Comment: Now that the question is edited, we see that it asks if these sets are a base for *some* topology, but perhaps not the usual one.

Comment: Yes, I see. I will fix my answer as well.